# Too much spacing in document

Tags: spacing

Suggestions needed to get rid of the space that is left blank by latex for no apparent reason.

I have tried `\vspace{-0.5}` but it is not helping. If I go any higher with we space the text overlaps other texts.

[image]

Comment: you haven't shown any code so we have to guess, but I guess you have `\flushbottom` (or a class that defaults to that) and something big on the next page means it can not have any more text on this page so has to stretch. You could use `\raggedbottom` so the space goes to the end, or adjust the page breaking in other ways

Comment: From you comment just realized I have a rather long algorithm with [H] in position parameter. fixed it....

Comment: `[H]` (which was my idea originally) means "please put an ugly white space in my document" The whole point of floating figures is to avoid the ugliness and the point of `[H]` is to stop floats...:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class is using `\flushbottom` so if no more text can be placed on the page then the text on this page will be stretched so the bottom baseline is at the bottom. Most likely you got an "underfull box" warning.

In comments you confirmed there was an `[H]` figure on the next page. The reason LaTeX moves floats is exactly to avoid this problem, to give more flexibility in page breaking to avoid white spaces. `[H]` makes the figure not a float, so it has to appear at that point in the text even if there has to be a bad page break to make it fit.

So the solutions would be to use `\raggedbottom` so excess space goes to the bottom of each page, or (often better) don't use `[H]` so latex can move the float and allow more text on to the page, so it does not need to stretch the space.

Comment: If you have multiline displayed equations, `\allowdisplaybreaks` could help, also.

Comment: Silly question: is `\flushbottom` global, what are the places you can use it? any dependencies?

Comment: @VScode_fanboy the settings are actually local but as its effect is only indirectly by affecting the asynchronous page breaker it only really makes sense to use at the start or after a forced page break.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle noted, but not checkd :)