# Incorrect vertical white space between paragraphs due to figure

Tags: spacing, floats

When inserting a figure in my latex document at a position where the figure cannot be placed precisely (e.g. at the bottom of a page in the pdf document), Latex nevertheless inserts white space between the two paragraphs around the figure.
This is an MWE:

```
\newline \lipsum[100]

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics{path/to/fig}
 \caption{This is a figure.}\label{fig:sample}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[100]
```

The output is shown below (the figure is placed on the following page):

[image]

Inserting `\raggedbottom` (see e.g. [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267623/too-much-spacing-in-document)) to the preamble already gives a smaller spacing between the paragraphs, see below (again with the figure on the next page):

[image]

However, I do not succeed in removing the white space entirely. How could this be solved?

Comment: Do you happen to have `\usepackage{parskip}` in the preamble, or have you set the `\parskip` length to some value above zero?

Comment: please always post the complete document that produces the image so that people can test answers. you can use `example-image` as th eimage name as that image is already in most tex installations

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the tip. Will keep in mind for the following requests. However, `example-image` did not work on my pc.
@TorbjørnT.: I am using the memoir class, that apparently emulates the parskip package. Adding `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` in the preamble solves the issue. Could you make a full answer of it so I can accept it?

Comment: if I change the version in my answer to `memoir` and add `\nonzeroparskip` instead of the parskip package I still don't get the doubled space.

Comment: The presence of a `figure` environment between paragraphs has no effect on the vertical spacing bewteen them; probably, you are deceived by the fact that, if you remove the figure, the page builder is able to find a better page break and, consequently, the space between those paragraphs is not stretched that much.  Are those the only two paragraphs that happen to fall within that particular page?

Comment: This is an issue related to a long document (100+ pages) and I have verified this behaviour for 7 different figures. Only consecutive paragraphs with a figure in between show this behaviour. I will try to make an MWE with a preamble and will adjust my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The posted fragment does not produce the image shown (the `\newline` would generate an error and there is only one paragraph after the figure)

If I complete it to a document as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics,lipsum,parskip}
\begin{document}

x
\newline \lipsum[100]

\begin{figure}[p]
 \centering
 \includegraphics{example-image}
 \caption{This is a figure.}\label{fig:sample}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[98-100]

\end{document}
```

Then the spacing is as expected:

[image]